# Android appCompat issue with samsung and wiko

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

currently I have a little problem with my application, everything works fine on most devices but on some samsung and wiko I get this error : 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder

I saw some answers on the internet where they said to add the line below in the proguard file, in my case this doesn't work

```
 -keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**, ** { *; }
```

My app is compound of 2 modules(so I have 2 proguard file), 1module is for the main app and the other is for a library

here is my gradle file for thr app module:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.refresh.quickeer"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug
            {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.xgc1986.android:parallaxpagertransformer:1.0.3'
compile project(':library')
}
```

[image]
Does somebody have a solution to this problem please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before encountering this issue I did not use proguard on my app. I resolved the issue by setting `minifyEnabled true` and using the following proguard config

```
-dontshrink    
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,** {*;}
-keepattributes **
-dontwarn **
```

I tested my app on [appthwack](https://appthwack.com/) before and after this fix to verify that it worked.

Comment: minifyEnabled false causes a gradle error and even with the proguard configuration it still doesn't work

Comment: I don't think proguard is even run if minifyEnabled is false

Comment: If you want to take a look at my build.gradle and proguard configs they're available at https://github.com/abaker/tasks

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why your app work on my phone but mine doesn't want to

Comment: Try setting minifyEnabled to true and just using my proguard config and the same default proguard file I'm using. My proguard file is supposed to do nothing but fix this issue

Comment: Indeed the preoblem was caused by the minifyEnables which was on set false. thanks for the answer, could you explain me what is the role of minifyEnabled please ?

Comment: Doesn't dontshrink defeat the purpose of an optimized apk?

Comment: @Waza_Be - in my case I did not want proguard to do anything besides obfuscate the name of the class that was causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you are talking about, here is the Google

### Here is what I use to fix `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder`:

```
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.** {*;}
```

### Here is everything that works for Support v4 and v7:

```
##################################################################################
#
# App Compat
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441366/note-android-support-v4-text-icucompatics-cant-find-dynamically-referenced-cl
#
##################################################################################
-dontnote android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
# -keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }  # <-- excess notes
# -keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
# Allow obfuscation of android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**
# to avoid problem on Samsung 4.2.2 devices with appcompat v21
# see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.** {*;}  # <-- important
```

**Source:** [Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatIcs: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441366/note-android-support-v4-text-icucompatics-cant-find-dynamically-referenced-cl) and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377

Comment: It should, this is used for plenty of users: https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Burrows+Apps. How are you testing this?

Comment: I just add your code in my ":app" proguard file and run the application

Comment: Make sure you clean. Are you testing on the Samsung? This is the **complete** answer from the Google issue.

Comment: i'm testing on a WIKO. When I delete this line from the code  setSupportActionBar(toolbar); the app launched correctly but crash when  i click on the multitask button

Comment: That maybe why. This solution is good for `Samsung` which is the widely most used Android device. Atleast you will still support the majority.