# Android app won't run on samsung device appcompat

Tags: android

I have updated the `Android Studio`, `Gradle` and my libraries to last versions and now when I try to run my APP on samsung devices I get the foollowing error:

```
08-09 11:31:36.037  24120-24120/com.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 24120
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:324)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.marian.digimusicstream.musicPlayer.onCreate(musicPlayer.java:95)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried to use the proguard file as it's describe here: [Crash: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614538/crash-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rlayout) but with no results, is there a way how to fix this ?

I've tested my app on LG G3 and Nexus 7 succesfully and on Samsung S4 mini and S2 the app Crash when it's opened.

Comment: Have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871727/android-appcompat-issue-with-samsung-and-wiko

Comment: @ThomasR.didn't helped me, I added the lines to proguard and changing the setting but it's the same.